# Several problems after Angular v11 to v12 upgrade

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, angular11, angular12

When I upgraded my Angular app from 11 to 12, I encountered the following issues:

1. The development section of file *angular.json* disappeared
2. Visual Studio Code breakpoints would no longer be hit
3. Production warning from [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what happened:  the Angular website has an upgrade helper that assists developers with determining the given upgrade steps for their combination of versions and libraries.   It's missing a step.   It’s rather simple what happened:

1. Visual Studio Code is unable to debug with breakpoints, because the upgrade forced my app into a production-only configuration.  The upgrade scripts removed my development section from my *angular.json* file.
2. Run the following to complete the missed step:

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.0
   ```